# exception problem with juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I run MAAS on vmware Workstaion and there is 4 ready client.When I run

```
sudo JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=ubuntu openstack-install
```

After some try I get

> exception problem with juju bootstrap

Below is commands log.

```
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:39, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:39, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:42, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:42, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:44, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:44, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:58, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:58, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:58, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/me/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 01-26 17:44:59, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 01-26 17:45:18, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 01-26 17:45:18, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/345a3085-de6c-4e5f-bc7f-251680dc5262/IL"'
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:45:50, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[ERROR: 01-26 17:45:55, utils.py:312] Problem with package install: Command 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /usr/bin/apt-get -qyf -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold install openstack-multi' returned non-zero exit status 100
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:45:55, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:45:55, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/me/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap  --to ubuntu
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:46:09, multi.py:145] Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': '', 'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\nBootstrap failed, destroying environment\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: cannot start bootstrap instance: cannot run instances: cannot run instances: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 409 CONFLICT (No available node matches constraints: name=ubuntu)\n', 'status': 1}'
[ERROR: 01-26 17:46:09, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[ERROR: 01-26 17:46:09, gui.py:270] Problem with juju bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 146, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:46:09, error.py:35] showing error view for: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[ERROR: 01-26 17:46:11, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 500, in process_input
    event, button, col, row, focus=True ):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1169, in mouse_event
    event, button, col, row-htrim, focus )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 903, in mouse_event
    event, button, col, row-top, focus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1687, in mouse_event
    focus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 666, in mouse_event
    focus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1687, in mouse_event
    focus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 557, in mouse_event
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/views/error.py", line 66, in cancel
    raise SystemExit("Install exited because of error.")
SystemExit: Install exited because of error.
[DEBUG: 01-26 17:46:11, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.6-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 01-26 17:46:11, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

Comment: Your error is due to JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=ubuntu, Juju isn't able to get an instance with the name ubuntu

Comment: I can't find any constraint with keyword 'name' from here https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/reference-constraints.   If its hostname you can try again by setting the hostname of a ready client for JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO

Comment: "me@ubuntu-Cloud:~$ sudo JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=ubuntu-Cloud openstack-install" the format of hostname is correct?